# SQL query running very slow - postrges

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

This query currently take 4 minutes to run:

```
with name1 as (
  select col1 as a1, col2 as a2, sum(FEE) as a3
  from s1, date
  where return_date = datesk and year = 2000
  group by col1, col2
)
select  c_id
from name1 ala1, ss, cc
where ala1.a3 > (
    select avg(a3) * 1.2 from name1 ctr2
    where ala1.a2 = ctr2.a2
  )
  and s_sk = ala1.a2
  and s_state = 'TN'
  and ala1.a1 = c_sk
order by c_id
limit 100;
```

I have set `work_mem=’1000MB’` and `enable-nestloop=off`

EXPLAIN ANALYZE of this query is: http://explain.depesz.com/s/DUa

```
QUERY PLAN

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------
 Limit  (cost=59141.02..59141.09 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=253707.928..253707.940 rows=100 loops=1)
   CTE name1
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11091.33..11108.70 rows=1390 width=14) (actual time=105.223..120.358 rows=50441 loops=1)
           Group Key: s1.col1, s1.col2
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=2322.69..11080.90 rows=1390 width=14) (actual time=10.390..79.897 rows=55820 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: (s1.return_date = date.datesk)
                 ->  Seq Scan on s1  (cost=0.00..7666.14 rows=287514 width=18) (actual time=0.005..33.801 rows=287514 loops=1)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=2318.11..2318.11 rows=366 width=4) (actual time=10.375..10.375 rows=366 loops=1)
                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                       ->  Seq Scan on date  (cost=0.00..2318.11 rows=366 width=4) (actual time=5.224..10.329 rows=366 loops=1)
                             Filter: (year = 2000)
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 72683
   ->  Sort  (cost=48032.32..48032.39 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=253707.923..253707.930 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: cc.c_id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=43552.37..48031.65 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=253634.511..253696.291 rows=18976 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (cc.c_sk = ala1.a1)
               ->  Seq Scan on cc  (cost=0.00..3854.00 rows=100000 width=21) (actual time=0.009..18.527 rows=100000 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=43552.02..43552.02 rows=28 width=4) (actual time=253634.420..253634.420 rows=18976 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 668kB
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.30..43552.02 rows=28 width=4) (actual time=136.819..253624.375 rows=18982 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (ala1.a2 = ss.s_sk)
                           ->  CTE Scan on name1 ala1  (cost=0.00..43548.70 rows=463 width=8) (actual time=136.756..253610.817 rows=18982 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (a3 > (SubPlan 2))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 31459
                                 SubPlan 2
                                   ->  Aggregate  (cost=31.29..31.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=5.025..5.025 rows=1 loops=50441)
                                         ->  CTE Scan on name1 ctr2  (cost=0.00..31.27 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.032..3.860 rows=8241 loops=50441)
                                               Filter: (ala1.a2 = a2)
                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 42200
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=12 width=4) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=12 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on ss  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=12 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.033 rows=12 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (s_state = 'TN'::bpchar)
 Planning time: 0.316 ms
 Execution time: 253708.351 ms
(36 rows)
```

With enable_nestloop=on;
EXPLAIN ANLYZE result is : http://explain.depesz.com/s/NPo

```
QUERY PLAN

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------
 Limit  (cost=54916.36..54916.43 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=257869.004..257869.015 rows=100 loops=1)
   CTE name1
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11091.33..11108.70 rows=1390 width=14) (actual time=92.354..104.103 rows=50441 loops=1)
           Group Key: s1.col1, s1.col2
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=2322.69..11080.90 rows=1390 width=14) (actual time=9.371..68.156 rows=55820 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: (s1.return_date = date.datesk)
                 ->  Seq Scan on s1  (cost=0.00..7666.14 rows=287514 width=18) (actual time=0.011..25.637 rows=287514 loops=1)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=2318.11..2318.11 rows=366 width=4) (actual time=9.343..9.343 rows=366 loops=1)
                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
                       ->  Seq Scan on date  (cost=0.00..2318.11 rows=366 width=4) (actual time=4.796..9.288 rows=366 loops=1)
                             Filter: (year = 2000)
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 72683
   ->  Sort  (cost=43807.66..43807.73 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=257868.994..257868.998 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: cc.c_id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..43806.98 rows=28 width=17) (actual time=120.358..257845.941 rows=18976 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..43633.22 rows=28 width=4) (actual time=120.331..257692.654 rows=18982 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (ala1.a2 = ss.s_sk)
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 208802
                     ->  CTE Scan on name1 ala1  (cost=0.00..43548.70 rows=463 width=8) (actual time=120.316..257652.636 rows=18982 loops=1)
                           Filter: (a3 > (SubPlan 2))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 31459
                           SubPlan 2
                             ->  Aggregate  (cost=31.29..31.31 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=5.105..5.105 rows=1 loops=50441)
                                   ->  CTE Scan on name1 ctr2  (cost=0.00..31.27 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.032..3.952 rows=8241 loops=50441)
                                         Filter: (ala1.a2 = a2)
                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 42200
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.21 rows=12 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=12 loops=18982)
                           ->  Seq Scan on ss  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=12 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.012 rows=12 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (s_state = 'TN'::bpchar)
               ->  Index Scan using cc_pkey on cc  (cost=0.29..6.20 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=18982)
                     Index Cond: (c_sk = ala1.a1)
 Planning time: 0.453 ms
 Execution time: 257869.554 ms
(34 rows)
```

Many other queries run quickly with enable_nestloop=off, there is no big difference for this query. Raw data is not really big, so 4 minutes is too much. I was expecting around 4-5 seconds.

Why is it taking so long !? 
I tried this in both postgres versions 9.4 and 9.5. It is same. Maybe I can create brin indexes. But I am not sure for which columns to create.

Configuration setting:

```
effective_cache_size         | 89GB 
shared_buffers               | 18GB
work_mem                     | 1000MB
maintenance_work_mem         | 500MB
checkpoint_segments          | 32
constraint_exclusion         | on
checkpoint_completion_target | 0.5
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what the query is doing and provide sample daa and desired results.  There might be better ways to write the logic.

Comment: can you also prefix all the columns with the tables so that we know where the `s_sk` and `s_state` came from

Comment: Your query plan appears to be telling you that the correlated subquery in your `WHERE` clause is very expensive.  That should come as no surprise, as correlated subqueries are notorious for causing performance issues.   Yours appears to require a full table scan of the CTE every time it is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

Like John Bollinger commented, your sub-query gets evaluated for each row of the main query. But since you are averaging on a simple column, you can easily move the sub-query out to a CTE and calculate the average once, which should speed up things tremendously:

```
with name1 as (
  select col1 as a1, col2 as a2, sum(FEE) as a3
  from s1, date
  where return_date = datesk and year = 2000
  group by col1, col2
), avg_a3_by_a2 as (
  select a2, avg(a3) * 1.2 as avg12
  from name1
  group by a2
)
select c_id
from name1, avg_a3_by_a2, ss, cc
where name1.a3 > avg_a3_by_a2.avg12
  and name1.a2 = avg_a3_by_a2.a2
  and s_sk = name1.a2
  and s_state = 'TN'
  and name1.a1 = c_sk
order by c_id
limit 100;
```

The new CTE calculates the average + 20% for every distinct value of `a2`.

Please also use the `JOIN` syntax instead of comma-separated `FROM` items as it makes your code far more readable. And if you start using aliases in your query, use them consistently on all tables and columns. I could correct neither of these two issues because of lack of information.